# Data table select top 5 rows

Tags: c#, datatable

Hi is there any way to select top 5 rows from a data table without iteration?

Comment: Why not adapt the underlaying select you are building your dataTable/dataSet with? - [google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+select+top) everything else would be an iteration...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "without iteration". One way or another, if you wish to enumerate data in a collection of any form, you will have to iterate that data at some point. Even if you use LINQ's .Take() statement, you will eventually iterate over however many records you take.

Comment: @jrista, you could always do `row[0], row[1], ..., row[4]` and avoid iteration :-)

Comment: @darin: at least you use no index-variable :)

Comment: which framework are building against?

Comment: @Darin: You would still be iterating with that...just with an "unfolded" loop...unfolded or not, the concept is the same. One way or another, you have to "iterate" the rows to get at their data. The only conclusion I can come to is that I am misunderstanding the OP's meaning/understanding of the word 'iteration' in this context.

Comment: there ain't direct way in .net 2.0

have a look at this solution http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/15478/select-top-10-from-a-datatable.aspx

Answer (score 17):

I think, You can use LINQ:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().Take(5);
```

Comment: that's basically an iteration. this is exactly what the querist didn't want!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair, as I understand, querist doesn't want to write his own code with iterations.

Comment: @Andreas: Technically speaking, calling `.AsEnumerable().Take(5)` is **not** an iteration...yet. However, one way or another, an iteration will be required to enumerate the data represented by that query...so I don't fully understand the OP's goal.

Comment: @belousov: that's why i did not downvote :)
@jrista: calling a method is no iteration, but it will end up in an iteration...

Comment: datatable.AsEnumerable().Take(5); 
is ok..but i am using VS 2005, this code wont work in it.thats my problem

Comment: there ain't direct way in .net 2.0

have a look at this solution http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/15478/select-top-10-from-a-datatable.aspx

Comment: Pavel Belousov, Correct syntax is follows. yourDatatable.AsEnumerable().OfType<DataRow>().Take(5).CopyToDataTable(); Thanks

Comment: @Ramakrishnankt yep your method works clear, because i use the code for pass to gridview

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 of the above posts, the following works for me:

```
foreach (DataRow _dr in DataSet.Tables[<tblname>].Select("", "Timestamp DESC").AsEnumerable().OfType<DataRow>().Take(5))
```

So now you can normally filter if you want, order if you want and then get only the amount of records that you want and then iterate through them whether it is 1 or 100.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
datatable.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for my needs.

```
public static DataTable TopRows(this DataTable dTable, int rowCount)
    {
        DataTable dtNew = dTable.Clone();
        dtNew.BeginLoadData();
        if (rowCount > dTable.Rows.Count) { rowCount = dTable.Rows.Count; }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount;i++)
        {
            DataRow drNew = dtNew.NewRow();
            drNew.ItemArray = dTable.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            dtNew.Rows.Add(drNew);
        }
        dtNew.EndLoadData();
        return dtNew;
    }
```

to use it you then do this:

```
dataTable.TopRows(5);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you use a LINQ statement, you could use the `Take()` method.

This [post](http://projectserverblogs.com/?p=2159) may be of some assistance as well.

**EDIT**

As you are using VS2005, use the `SELECT()` method in the datatable like so:

```
DataRow[] rows = datatable.Select('TOP 5');
```

Comment: but am getting an error :Filter expression ''Top 5'' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.