# cast is not a member of system.data.rowcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to select top 5 rows from datatable.

For that i used following query:

```
DTResult
    .Rows
    .Cast(Of System.Data.DataRow)()
    .Take(Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

But its giving me following error:

`cast is not a member of system.data.rowcollection`

I removed cast and made it like:

```
DTResult.AsEnumerable.Take(Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()))
```

But in both case it gives me error, and also:

its not autosuggesting `.Take()`

plz help me.

Comment: Check this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243589/data-table-select-top-5-rows

Comment: @Shreyas with that post only i made above query and i have got problem in it

Comment: I think DtResult is DataTable then use DTResult.AsEnumerable().Take(int.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString())); instead of DTResult.AsEnumerable.Take(Integer.Parse(ddlPage.SelectedValue.ToString()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use LINQ (e.g. `Take()` or `Cast()`) and the [DataTableExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) (e.g. `dataTable.AsEnumerable()`), ensure you have referenced the right assemblies and importet the right namespaces.

The assemblies are `System.Core.dll` for LINQ , and `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` for the DataTableExtensions.

The namespaces you need are `System.Linq` and `System.Data`.

Comment: yeah, System.Linq i had not imported, that was the problem..thanx

Answer (score 0):

In framework 3.5,

```
dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(5)
```

Otherwise use following code

```
 public DataTable  SelectTopDataRow(DataTable dt, int count)
{
 DataTable dtn = dt.Clone();
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
 {
     dtn.ImportRow(dt.Rows[i]);
 }

 return dtn;
}
```